# scanf and entering characters

Tags: c

I was wondering what happens if in my program I ask for an integer input using `scanf("%d",&num)` and the user enters a string of chars and ints for example `at3stf0rfun`.
What would be the value of `num` in that case? Does it take only the integers `30` or does it also convert the chars to its' ASCII decimal values?

Comment: Try it out and find out for yourself :)

Comment: does it hurt to try it for yourself?

Comment: You could try reading the documentation instead of just wondering and running to SO.

Comment: I am all for trying stuff out, but in this instance it's better to consult the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scanning stops on encountering invalid input. Therefore, in your code the value of `num` will remain unchanged.

To detect whether this is what happened you need to examine the return value of `scanf`. To quote  `man scanf`:

> RETURN VALUES
>
> These functions return the number of input items assigned.  This can
>   be  fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of a matching
>   failure.  Zero indicates that, although there was input available,
>   no conversions were assigned; **typically this is due to an invalid
>   input character,  such as an alphabetic character for a `%d'
>   conversion**.  The value EOF is  returned if an input failure occurs
>   before any conversion such as an end-of-file occurs.  If an error or
>   end-of-file occurs after conversion has  begun, the number of
>   conversions which were successfully completed is  returned.